# I have a buffer overflow problem while writing mergesort() in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort, buffer-overflow

The prompt question is, the size of the help array that can be written is (R-L+1)*'4' bytes, but '8' bytes may be written, what does this mean?Is the array out of bounds, but I think it is logically correct, the specific code is as follows：

```
void merge(int a[], int L, int M, int R) {
    int* help = new int[R - L + 1];
    int i = 0;
    int p = L;
    int q = M + 1;
    while (p <= M && q <= R) {
        help[i++] = a[p] <= a[q] ? a[p++] : a[q++];
    }
    while (p <= M) {
        help[i++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (q <= R) {

        help[i++] = a[i++];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < R - L + 1; i++) {
        a[L + i] = help[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a memory leak as well.

Comment: `help[i++] = a[i++];` is wrong in *both* places, and the latter isn't even needed if you plan it out correctly. The lower finish, however, should be `while (p <= M) { help[i++] = a[p++]; }`. If you want to fix the other half, do so.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code? If you step through it statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, no indexes will be out of bounds?

Comment: I actually made a logical error in this code, resulting in an infinite loop